# How to calculate [10^10^10^10^10^-10^10]?

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

How to find an integer part of $10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{-10^{10}}}}}}$? It looks like it is slightly above $10^{10^{10}}$.

Comment: Either I am temorarily confused or I do not understand this question. (-10)^10 = 10^10, so? Or is there a typo?

Comment: Only slightly related, but for amusement, check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72646/help-me-put-these-enormous-numbers-in-order-googol-googol-plex-bang-googol-s

Comment: @quid: It is -10^10, not (-10)^10.

Comment: @GH: Thanks! So, it was me being confused. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Dear Vladimir, I dont think so. Evaluate using the approximation exp x is close to 1+x when x is small (so 10^x is close to 1+log_e 10 x, and also 10^{a+b}=10^a 10^b. Is there a research motivation behind this cute) question?

Comment: Just for curiosisty: Was there any context for the appearance of this number?

Comment: @EFinat-S I experimented with various power towers, just for fun, and then I thought: is it possible to construct a non-trivial problem about power towers that results in a “small” number (i.e. a number whose decimal expansion is practically possible to fully write down), and I came up with this question.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I think the number in question is $10^{10^{10}}+10^{11}\ln^4(10)$ plus a tiny positive number. That is, it starts with a digit $1$, followed by $10^{10}-13$ zeros, then by the string $2811012357389$, then a decimal point, and then some garbage (which starts like $4407116278\dots$).

To see this let $x:=10^{-10^{10}}$, a tiny positive number, and put $c:=\ln(10)$, an important constant. We have
$$10^x=1+cx+O(x^2)$$
$$10^{10^x}=10^{1+cx+O(x^2)}=10+10c^2x+O(x^2)$$
$$10^{10^{10^x}}=10^{10+10c^2x+O(x^2)}=10^{10}+10^{11}c^3x+O(x^2)$$
$$10^{10^{10^{10^x}}}=10^{10^{10}+10^{11}c^3x+O(x^2)}=10^{10^{10}}+10^{10^{10}}10^{11}c^4x+O(x^2),$$
where $O(x^2)$ means something tiny all the way.

In the last expression we have $10^{10^{10}}10^{11}c^4x=10^{11}c^4$, which justifies my claim.

Comment: I'm not convinced the question belongs on MO, but I like the answer too much to vote the question down. 

Comment: @Gerry: I thought the same! :-)

Comment: Robert Munafo has a "hypercalc", unfortunately not for the windows-environment, so I cannot use it (Actually it is a perl-script). http://mrob.com/pub/perl/index.html  cite: "Hypercalc: An unusual calculator program.    
 It represents numbers in a special way allowing the calculation of quantities much larger than tools such as bc, dc,
 MACSYMA/maxima, Mathematica and Maple, all of which use a bignum library. 
For example, you can use Hypercalc to determine whether 128^48^1024 is larger than 8^88^888. (...)" (from R. Munafo's site). Someone who could try it with this program?

Comment: As far as I can tell, hypercalc just uses standard floating point representations of iterated logs.  This suggests that it cannot handle the sort of precision necessary here.